# Why does Jenkins delete files starting with dots?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I use a bundle of Jenkins + Gitlab and that's when my pipeline starts its work, I observe the absence of all files starting with a dot

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
       stage('Initialization') {
          steps {
             sh 'ls -l'
             updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'Build&Deploy', state: 'pending'
             git branch: env.gitlabBranch, credentialsId: 'id', url: 'link'
          }
       }
   }}
```

Example of a deleted file

1. .env
2. .eslintrc.ls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unix command `ls -l` executed within the shell interpreter used by the `sh` step method will not show files beginning with a `.`. You need to update the method argument to:

```
sh('ls -la')
```